# Katharsis Json Api restrict PATCH

Tags: java, spring-boot, json-api, katharsis

I am using Katharsis library in my Spring Boot server to build automatically JSON-API interface.

Let's say I have an endpoint (resource) /resource, for which I would like to offer POST method (to create new resources) but restrict PATCH (to restrict resources updating).
Meanwhile, the io.katharsis.repository.ResourceRepository offers only save() method, which applies to both POST and PATCH.

My only idea at the moment is to add another Filter to FilterChain that will disallow PATCHing the required endpoint.

Are there any better (i.e. shorter or more elegant) ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable PATCH method you should follow the steps:

1. Check if in Database exists object with ID provided in requested URL
2. If object exists, throw [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is this the way that JsonApi somehow recommends? My doubt is: why should I even ask the database? I know that PATCH is unsupported at all, regardless of what is in the database. So, it sounds like one extra database call that can be skipped, right? After reading my question again - maybe it is not clear enough, I will correct it.

Comment: Also, I would greatly appreciate even a short explanation, why this solution is better than adding filter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usage of filter would be more appropriate if you'd want to disable patch for all requests and I assume you don't want to do that. Considering skipping first step - in production deployment cases with huge amounts of transaction and requests presumably only DB layer would know whether the object truly already exists. It's mostly for data consistency.

Comment: Thanks again. I decided to accept this answer, as long as there is no other option. It can be indeed considered more elegant than Filter

Answer (score 0):

A PATCH contains an ID.
So you could check if ID != null and throw an error instead.
On this way you don't need to check the database.
This solution assumes that you don't generate id's on the client.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea. 
In our API it is actually allowed to both 
POST resource/{id} and 
PATCH resource/{id}.
So, as you wrote this one won't work. Honestly, I stayed with Filter (matching every PATCH /resource request) solution to avaid database query.